# One or two commas when using an "adjectival aside"?

Tags: grammaticality, commas

I never quite know if, following proper rules of punctuation, I *need* to place one or two commas in sentences such as:

> We owe another, highly lucid, description of the principle to...
>
> We owe another, highly lucid description of the principle to...

or, alternatively, whether I'm allowed to *choose*, with the first version being more of an 'aside', and the second stressing the 'lucid' aspect.

But I'm purely intuiting here, which is why I was hoping for some comments.

Comment: I don't know why you need to put any commas at all in that sentence.

Comment: You might say your intuition in wrong, on both counts. But you should say your intuition is wrong on both counts.

Answer (score -3):

This is known as the Oxford comma and most style guides support the use use of the additional comma.

Comment: I thought the Oxford comma was the second comma in *"apples, oranges, and bananas."*

Comment: The Oxford comma (aka [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)) is used, as @PeterShor, showed, in a list, primarily (IMO) to indicate that the last pair of list items are separate rather than a compound noun.  Some folks say it's not necessary but [they are *wrong*](https://qz.com/932004/the-oxford-comma-a-maine-court-settled-the-grammar-debate-over-serial-commas-with-a-ruling-on-overtime-pay-for-dairy-truck-drivers/).